# How to change Menu item background color in android

Tags: android

In android 2.3 menu items are in black color and text in white color but i want change that color is possible?

Answer (score -1):

Do you really want to change how the menu's look? I can't think of a single app that does that.

If you think you want to do this because your existing icons look bad, then you can create new versions of them and put them in /res/drawable-v9/ This will ensure that your new icons only show up in Gingerbread and higher.

Comment: hai mike thanks for the answer but its is possible through parsing.. just check out the below link posted by Dynamic Mind in which you can find the answer in Halo Ha's posting..

Comment: Mike dg never said it was not possible, he just pointed out that you shouldn't do it.

Comment: It's definitely possible, just hacky, and non-standard.

Comment: The question was how to do what OP was asking, not whether it was the right thing to do or not

Comment: "Do you really want to change how the menu's look?" Yes, It's a quick and easy way to implement toggled menu items.